# Policy for writing to memory

Tags: caching, paging, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory, cpu-cache

I understand that when need to deliver data to the CPU:

1. On a cache miss we access the cache, access the DRAM:

   a) we copy the data from the DRAM back to the cache if it is a DRAM hit.
     b) we copy the data from the disk to the DRAM and then from the DRAM to the cache.
2. On a cache hit we just access the cache.

What is the policy that we should use when we write to memory?

For example:

In every write cache hit do we update the cache, DRAM, and the disk?

For every write miss, do we write to the disk, read that disk block into DRAM, 
and then read the DRAM block into the cache?

Answer (score 3):

Most modern CPUs have cache so much faster than DRAM that write-back is the only policy that makes sense.  Some older CPUs or modern embedded may have write-through CPU caches when the gap between on-chip cache and DRAM isn't so huge.  Either way this is hardware-managed and invisible to software.

**But writes always stop at DRAM, if/when they make it that far**.  The "backing store" on disk is not important when the page is in DRAM.  If you want to think about DRAM as cache for a memory-mapped file (or the pagefile for anonymous memory), the only write policy that makes sense for performance is write-back!

**Write-back to disk is managed by software**, so implementing a write-through policy would require making every store trap to the OS after committing to DRAM, at which point the OS would have to run a bunch of code to initiate a SATA write command of the whole page.  (And would have to do this without accessing any DRAM itself, otherwise how would *those* writes get in sync on disk?  Or maybe you'd let yourself off the hook here because kernel memory is generally not pageable, so this kernel code is only backed by DRAM, not ultimately by disk pages.)

Even if disk-write was efficiently possible with byte or word granularity (which it very much isn't unless your "disk" is actually non-volatile RAM like 3D XPoint (e.g. [Optane DC Persistent Memory](https://superuser.com/questions/1389552/can-intel-optane-memory-compensate-for-less-ram/1391391#1391391)), or battery-backed DRAM), just trapping every store would still destroy performance, like hundreds of times slower.

The gap between DRAM and disk has always been huge; hardware doesn't have mechanisms to make efficient write-through to "disk" possible.  Other than modern non-volatile storage connected to the memory bus so it can be truly memory-mapped, like Linux `mmap(MAP_SYNC)`.  But then there's no plain DRAM in between cpu-cache and persistent NV-DRAM

---

**I/O vs. DRAM performance**; random DRAM writes (on a modern x86, using cache-bypassing NT stores) takes something like ~60ns with 64-byte granularity (for a burst write of a full cache line), including time spent getting the store from a CPU core to a memory controller.  (60ns is actually something like the L3-miss load-use latency for reads but I'm going to assume something similar for NT stores.)

Random disk writes to a rotational magnetic disk take about 10ms, so that's about 6 orders of magnitude slower.  And to even detect

**Also, disk writes have a minimum size of usually 512 or 4096** bytes (1 hardware sector), so to write 1 byte or word, or a CPU cache line, would take a read-modify-write cycle for the disk.